# Facebook Uncaught SecurityError

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm currently looking to make a Facebook JavaScript App. As such I'm literally just copy pasting out of the docs into my page and I keep getting the following errors in the console:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. VM2813:1
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
 VM2817:1
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

As such I then looked to add `http://localhost:8080` to my Facebook app page and yet I'm still getting the same error.[image]

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<body>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '644205045632878',
          status     : true,
          xfbml      : true
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
</body>
```

Please can someone explain what is wrong here. This is my first time doing this...

Comment: I guess you have "Secure Browsing" enabled in your user's settings, therefore your server also needs to be able to respond via HTTPS...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you are testing with **Chrome with the Ripple emulator installed** when you see these error messages, try disabling Ripple (from settings, not just for the particular page).  Evidently even when Ripple isn't enabled for a particular page, it intercepts the response and gets in the way.

I observed this with Chrome version 34.0.1847.131 on Windows 7 Pro 64-bit with the Ripple Emulator (Beta) 0.9.15 extension installed and enabled.

Comment: Thanks! Error went away when I got rid of it. It was never of any use to me anyway.

Comment: Same on linux Version 47.0.2526.73 (64-bit). I didn't even realise this was installed, I suspect it comes with "Web Developer" tools, either that or chrome installs and enables it by default

Answer (score 0):

As @peterr pointed out you must disable the **Ripple** from the `Extensions` (http://chrome://extensions/) only:
[image]

Disabling it from here **won't work**:

[image]