# Facebook integration with website - protocol error [http/https]

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I decided to integrate the FB login/sharing capability to my website. However I am not able to make even the simple like script work as I get http//https protocol error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://staticxx.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.my-site.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

The code I copy pasted from [FB docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=505598882820893";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

In fact I get the same error when I run the login [script](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web).

I looked at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735446/facebook-login-blocked-a-frame-issue) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892556/facebook-unsafe-javascript-issue-document-domain-values-should-be-same?lq=1) but they didnt work in  my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it. Thanks to this other question: [Facebook Uncaught SecurityError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361362/facebook-uncaught-securityerror)

DISABLE 'RIPPLE EMULATOR' from chrome extensions.